# Issue with Update record in angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript, api, web-services

angular version:
Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.7

I want to update a record and when I click on edit icon and then my record is going to form and then I changes some filed of record and then click On Edit Button then My record is update in browser(console log) but not update in database??

backendservice.ts

```
       //when I click on edit icon then record going to form 

public editpartymaster(PartyMstId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
            let options = { headers: headers, crossDomain: true, withCredentials: true };

            var url = "http://localhost:000/PartyMsts/EditPatymaster?PartyMstId=" + PartyMstId;

             this.httpClient.post<any>(url, options).subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    resolve(res);
                },
                (err) => console.log(err)
            );
        });
    }

    //edit button click event

    public editpartymasterid(PartyMstId, PartyCode, PartyName, Address, PhNo1, SDate, PartyDate, RDType, Exchange) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
            let options = { headers: headers, crossDomain: true, withCredentials: true };

            var url = "http://localhost:000/PartyMsts/EditPatymaster";

            const postdata = {
                'PartyMstId': PartyMstId,
                'PartyCode': PartyCode,
                'PartyName': PartyName,
                'Address': Address,
                'PhNo1': PhNo1,
                'SDate': SDate,
                'PartyDate': PartyDate,
                'RDType': RDType,
                'Exchange': Exchange
            }

            console.log("formdata", postdata)

            return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, postdata)
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    console.log("res partyadd add 198", res);
                    resolve(res);
                });
        });
    }
```

partymaster.component.ts

```
    PartyMstId: any;
    PartyCode: any;
    PartyName: any;
    Address: any;
    PhNo1: any;
    SDate: any;
    PartyDate: any;
    RDType: any;
    Exchange: any;
    x: any;
    y: any;
    c: any;
    partylist: any;

   constructor(public myservice: BackendService) {}
//edit icon click event

onGridRowClicked(e: any) {
        if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
            let actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type");
            if (actionType == "edit") {
                console.log("e", e.data.PartyMstId);
                console.log("View edit action clicked");
                this.myservice.editpartymaster(e.data.PartyMstId).then((data: any) => {
                    if (data.message == "your record update") {

                        this.PartyMstId = e.data.PartyMstId;
                        this.PartyCode = e.data.PartyCode;
                        this.PartyName = e.data.PartyName;
                        this.Address = e.data.Address;
                        this.PhNo1 = e.data.PhNo1;
                        this.SDate = e.data.SDate;
                        this.PartyDate = e.data.PartyDate;
                        this.RDType = e.data.RDType;
                        this.Exchange = e.data.Exchange;
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (actionType == "delete") {
                console.log("View delete action clicked");
            }

//edit button click event
    editbuttonclickevent() {
        console.log("---PartyMstId---", this.PartyMstId);
        console.log("---PartyCode---", this.PartyCode);
        console.log("---PartyName---", this.PartyName);
        console.log("---Address---", this.Address);
        console.log("---PhNo1---", this.PhNo1);
        console.log("---SDate---", this.SDate);
        console.log("---PartyDate---", this.PartyDate);
        console.log("---RDType---", this.RDType);
        console.log("---Exchange---", this.Exchange);

        this.myservice.editpartymasterid(this.PartyMstId, this.PartyCode,
            this.PartyName, this.Address, this.PhNo1, this.SDate, this.PartyDate,
            this.RDType, this.Exchange).then((data: any) => {
            console.log("list data")
            if (data.message == "your record update") {
                this.list();
            }
        });
    }
```

partymastercomponent.html

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"
 (rowClicked)='onGridRowClicked($event)'>
    </ag-grid-angular>

<button type="button" (click)="editbuttonclickevent()">Edit</button>
```

asp.net mvc service

```
        public ActionResult EditPatymaster(int PartyMstId)
        {
            var partymst = poly.PartyMsts.Find(PartyMstId);
            partymstmodel partymstupdate = new partymstmodel();

            partymstupdate.PartyCode = partymst.PartyCode;
            partymstupdate.PartyName = partymst.PartyName;
            partymstupdate.Address = partymst.Address;
            partymstupdate.PhNo1 = partymst.PhNo1;
            partymstupdate.SDate = partymst.SDate;
            partymstupdate.PartyDate = partymst.PartyDate;
            partymstupdate.RDType = partymst.RDType;
            return View(partymstupdate);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult EditPatymaster(partymstmodel partymst, int PartyMstId)
        {
            var partymstupdate = poly.PartyMsts.Find(PartyMstId);

            if(partymstupdate!=null)
            {
                partymstupdate.PartyCode = partymst.PartyCode;
                partymstupdate.PartyName = partymst.PartyName;
                partymstupdate.Address = partymst.Address;
                partymstupdate.PhNo1 = partymst.PhNo1;
                partymstupdate.SDate = partymst.SDate;
                partymstupdate.PartyDate = partymst.PartyDate;
                partymstupdate.RDType = partymst.RDType;

                HttpResponseMessage response = staticvariable.client.PutAsJsonAsync("PartyMsts", partymst).Result;

                var data = new
                {
                    message = "your record update",
                };
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                var data = new
                {
                    message = "your record not updated",
                };
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

problem is my console log is display updated record but my database filed is not update that is my problem??

browserlog:

[image]

My record is not update but browser console log is updated?

[image]

Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

from the console error it seems you have a CORS problem, Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, 
if you are using ASP API as back end, download the following nuget packages :

Microsoft.AspNet.Cors

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

and in your WebApiConfig class file, in methode Register add this line

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```

Comment: still give an error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:0000/PartyMsts/EditPatymaster' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. can u more help

Comment: @rajubhai are you sure you have modified the correct webconfig class ? go to app_start folder --> expend it --> search for WebAPIConfig.cs--> open --> then add in function Register this code --> config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));

Answer (score 0):

you should install `asp.net cors` and also config it in your back end server.it meant you should enable cors like this :

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

now you should enable your cors on your controller or method in back end like this

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

above way does not make any sense with `origin *` you can know about cors in  this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) and custom it